# Issue with getting value and concatenation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, concatenation, key-value

I have a simple script to resolve hostname into IP address and then create from it key-value pair to use in jenkins:

```
$ips = Resolve-DnsName -type a HOSTNAME | FT IPAddress -HideTableHeaders
echo $ips
>> 192.168.3.1
```

But when I want to use this output in key-value pair, I receve following:

```
$keyvalue = $(echo 'ipaddr:'"$ips")

PS C:\Users\vegas.s> echo $keyvalue
ipaddr:
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData    Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

I want to receive following:

```
ipaddr:192.168.3.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're storing the result of `Format-Table`. You should only use that when displaying stuff, and only as the very last element of a pipeline, not as an intermediate result. Leave that out and use `$ips.IPAddress` (`$($ips.IPAddress)` within a string) to get the propery value without adornment.

Comment: @JeroenMostert unfortunately, $ips.IPAddress didnt return anything - https://i.imgur.com/sOFTg31.png

Comment: Of course -- that's because you still have the `Format-Table` in there. Try `$ips = (Resolve-DnsName -type a www.google.com).IPAddress`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - youre right! When I use $ips = Resolve-DnsName -type a HOSTNAME    and    echo $ips.IPAddress - it returns correct value! You can arrange it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#join the string and ip separated by colon
$keyvalue = 'ipaddr',$ips -join ':'

PS C:\Users\vegas.s> echo $keyvalue
```